# Reprojecting vector geometry in place using C++ & GDAL

Tags: gdal, c++

I'm trying to implement a reprojection method in my C++ code using GDAL. I open a shape file, pass the pointer to the layer object to my method, and iterate through the features while retrojecting them to the new CRS. It compiles and runs with no issues, but the shape files are still in the original CRS. I have other methods that manipulate the data and the changes are successfully saved, but I just can't get this one method to work.

Outside of this method, I call `in_layer->SyncToDisk()`, and I delete the pointer using `delete pointer`, which writes to disk in the rest of my code.

Am I missing something here?

```
void ShapeEditor::reproject(OGRLayer *in_layer, int utm_zone) {
  /*
   * Reproject the layer.
   * @param in_layer: The layer to reproject
   * @param utm_zone: The UTM zone to reproject to
   */

  // Convert UTM zone integer into the EPSG code. This map will be updated
  // as new areas become active. the N specifier, e.g. 10N, is taken for
  // granted.
  std::map<int, int> utm_zones {
      {10, 26910},
      {11, 32611},
      {16, 32616}
  };

  // Proj library path
  const std::string ppath {std::filesystem::current_path().string()};
  const char * proj_path[] {ppath.c_str(), nullptr};
  std::cout << "Searching for proj.db in " << ppath << std::endl;
  OSRSetPROJSearchPaths(proj_path);

  int crs {};
  for (auto it {utm_zones.begin()}; it != utm_zones.end(); it++) {
      if (it->first == utm_zone) {
          crs = it->second;
      }
  }

  OGRSpatialReference *srFrom {in_layer->GetSpatialRef()};
  OGRSpatialReference *srTo = new OGRSpatialReference;

  std::cout << "Converting to EPSG: " << crs << std::endl;
  srTo->importFromEPSG(crs);
  OGRCoordinateTransformation *coordTrans {OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(srFrom, srTo)};

  for (OGRFeatureUniquePtr &feature : in_layer) {
      OGRGeometry *transformed {feature->GetGeometryRef()};
      transformed->transform(coordTrans);
      feature->SetGeometry(transformed);
      in_layer->SetFeature(feature.release());
  }

  delete srTo;
}
```

EDIT: Got it to work by creating a new dataset and layer, copying features to that, and saving to new shapefile. However, it's not writing a prj file.

```
void ShapeEditor::reproject(OGRLayer *in_layer, int utm_zone, std::string path) {
/*
 * Reproject the layer.
 * @param in_layer: The layer to reproject
 * @param utm_zone: The UTM zone to reproject to
 */

const char *pszDriverName {"ESRI Shapefile"};
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDriver *poDriver {nullptr};
poDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(pszDriverName);

// Convert UTM zone integer into the EPSG code. This map will be updated
// as new areas become active. the N specifier, e.g. 10N, is taken for
// granted.
std::map<int, int> utm_zones {
    {10, 26910},
    {11, 32611},
    {16, 32616}
};

// Proj library path
const std::string ppath {std::filesystem::current_path().string()};
const char * proj_path[] {ppath.c_str(), nullptr};
std::cout << "Searching for proj.db in " << ppath << std::endl;
OSRSetPROJSearchPaths(proj_path);

int crs {};
for (auto it {utm_zones.begin()}; it != utm_zones.end(); it++) {
    if (it->first == utm_zone) {
        crs = it->second;
    }
}

OGRSpatialReference *srFrom {in_layer->GetSpatialRef()};
OGRSpatialReference *srTo = new OGRSpatialReference;

std::cout << "Converting to EPSG: " << crs << std::endl;
srTo->importFromEPSG(crs);
OGRCoordinateTransformation *coordTrans {OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(srFrom, srTo)};

// Create new layer
GDALDataset *poDS {nullptr};
poDS = poDriver->Create(path.c_str(), 0, 0, 0, GDT_Unknown, NULL);
OGRLayer *poLayer {nullptr};
poLayer = poDS->CreateLayer("Reprojected", NULL, wkbUnknown, NULL);

char **papszOptions;
//papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "DIM", "2");
//poLayer = poDS->CreateLayer(path.c_str(), srTo, wkbUnknown, papszOptions);

for (OGRFeatureUniquePtr &feature : in_layer) {
    OGRGeometry *transformed {feature->GetGeometryRef()};
          transformed->transform(coordTrans);
          feature->SetGeometry(transformed);
          poLayer->CreateFeature(feature.get()->Clone());
          poLayer->SetFeature(feature.release());
}

// Cleanup
poLayer->SyncToDisk();
delete poLayer;
delete poDS;
delete coordTrans;
delete srTo;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The answer was partially covered in my edit, and adding the `OGRSpatialReference` object to the `poDS->CreateLayer` call. The complete working method follows:

```
void ShapeEditor::reproject(OGRLayer *in_layer, int utm_zone, std::string path) {
/*
 * Reproject the layer.
 * @param in_layer: The layer to reproject
 * @param utm_zone: The UTM zone to reproject to
 */

const char *pszDriverName {"ESRI Shapefile"};
GDALAllRegister();
GDALDriver *poDriver {nullptr};
poDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(pszDriverName);

// Convert UTM zone integer into the EPSG code. This map will be updated
// as new areas become active. the N specifier, e.g. 10N, is taken for
// granted.
std::map<int, int> utm_zones {
    {10, 26910},
    {11, 32611},
    {16, 32616}
};

// Proj library path
const std::string ppath {std::filesystem::current_path().string()};
const char * proj_path[] {ppath.c_str(), nullptr};
std::cout << "Searching for proj.db in " << ppath << std::endl;
OSRSetPROJSearchPaths(proj_path);

int crs {};
for (auto it {utm_zones.begin()}; it != utm_zones.end(); it++) {
    if (it->first == utm_zone) {
        crs = it->second;
    }
}

OGRSpatialReference *srFrom {in_layer->GetSpatialRef()};
OGRSpatialReference *srTo = new OGRSpatialReference;

std::cout << "Converting to EPSG: " << crs << std::endl;
srTo->importFromEPSG(crs);
OGRCoordinateTransformation *coordTrans {OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(srFrom, srTo)};

// Create new layer
GDALDataset *poDS {nullptr};
poDS = poDriver->Create(path.c_str(), 0, 0, 0, GDT_Unknown, NULL);
OGRLayer *poLayer {nullptr};
poLayer = poDS->CreateLayer("Reprojected", srTo, wkbUnknown, NULL);

for (OGRFeatureUniquePtr &feature : in_layer) {
    OGRGeometry *transformed {feature->GetGeometryRef()};
          transformed->transform(coordTrans);
          feature->SetGeometry(transformed);
          poLayer->CreateFeature(feature.get()->Clone());
          poLayer->SetFeature(feature.release());
}

// Cleanup
poLayer->SyncToDisk();
delete poLayer;
delete poDS;
delete coordTrans;
delete srTo;
```

}

Comment: I seem to be losing all of the fields on the features of a layer when doing this. It is all being replaced by a FID incrementing from 0-n. Any thoughts on this?